# How to find the named range of a cell - VSTO throws exception

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

To get named range of a cell, heres my code. Works ok if the clicked cell is on first sheet. But the moment I select a cell from some other sheet, it just throws the **Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC Error**

Saw similar question on stack but dint get the conclusion from those posts:
Here is my code:

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook _workbook = ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range Target = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveCell;
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Name name in _workbook.Names)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range intersectRange = _workbook.Application.Intersect(Target, name.RefersToRange);
                if (intersectRange != null)
                {
                    rangeName = name.Name;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: On what line is the exception thrown?

Comment: I'm curious. What is the `InteropReference` for? I don't recall ever needing (or seeing) that in my experience.

Comment: Thats a custom object. I 've updated code to ignore that thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use Intersect without throwing an error if the ranges are on different sheets.  Add a check to see whether each range's `Parent` property refer to the same sheet, before you try the `Intersect()`

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like `Globals.ThisAddIn.Excel` is an `Application` object. It may be a different instance than `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application`. According to http://www.ureader.com/message/692318.aspx using objects between two `Application`s can trigger your exception.

Try changing your code to use one or the other `Application` instance, not both.

Comment: Ah, I see you removed the reference to `Globals.ThisAddIn.Excel` in your question. Did you test it?

Answer (score 0):

try a simpler way to get the name

If Not (ActiveCell.ListObject Is Nothing) Then
    MsgBox ActiveCell.ListObject.Name
  End If